# Typing moment-timezone Variables

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, moment-timezone

I recently upgraded to stricter eslint rules and am running into issues typing moment-timezone variables.  In the below example `scheduleDate` is a string and `scheduleDateTime` is in need of some kind of explicit typing.

### Example

```
import * as moment from "moment-timezone";
...
const scheduleDateTime = moment.utc(scheduleDate);
```

### Errors

`@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call`

### Ref

[eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-call/), [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: Is the problem with `scheduleDateTime`, or with `scheduleDate`? If the error's on that line, it might be that `scheduleDate` is of type `any`.

Comment: `scheduleDataTime `is in need of typing.  `scheduleDate` is of type string.